# How to run a Function on a Player GMOD DarkRP Lua

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I am trying to make a muting script that doesn't let players talk. At the moment I am at telling which player in the script with no commands but I cant work out or find how to run this function that I created on a specific player, not just mute the entire server.

sv_mute.lua:

```
util.AddNetworkString( "mute_message" )

ismuted == false
targetPlayer == "Xx_Player_xX"

function checkmute()

    function SendMessage( ply, txt, pub )
        net.Start( "mute_message" )
            net.WriteString( "YOU ARE MUTED, SHUT UP" )
        net.Send( ply )
        return ""
    end
    hook.Add( "PlayerSay", "SendMessage", SendMessage, )
end

Player:checkmute(()targetPlayer)
```

cl_mute.lua:

```
function ReceiveMessage()
    local txt = net.ReadString()
    chat.AddText( Color( 0, 255, 0), txt)
end
```

I have so far got to using `Player:checkmute(()targetPlayer)` but I assume this is wrong

Comment: Please do yourself (and us) a favor an learn the language (and the libraries) you want to work with... I'll write an answer in a sec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at first a few mistakes I have seen on a first quick look.

- You defined a function without a parameter but you try to call it with one
- You did not used the tools Garry gave you already to send messages to players

---

## Things we will be using to achieve your desired task

- [`GM:PlayerSay( Player sender, string text, boolean teamChat )`](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/GM/PlayerSay)
- [`Player:PrintMessage( number type, string message )`](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Player/PrintMessage)

---

## The solution

```
-- sv_mute.lua

-- a list of muted players, you need to get them from somewhere (not part of this answer)
mutedPlayers = {
  "StupidMan" = true,
  "AnnoyingKid" = true,
  "ExGirlfriend" = true
}

-- the function that will check if a user is muted
local function checkMuted(--[[ string ]] playername)
  return mutedPlayers[playername]
  -- you probably need to change the code to something else
  -- based on how you store your muted players
end

hook.Add("PlayerSay", "VosemMute_PlayerSay", function(sender, message, teamChat)
  if ( checkMuted(sender:GetName()) ) then
    sender.PrintMessage(HUD_PRINTTALK, "You are muted!")
    return "" -- this will suppress the message
  end
end)
```

---

## Some helpful links

- [HUD Enumerations (`HUD_PRINTTALK`)](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Enums/HUD)
- [`Player:GetName()`](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Player/GetName)
- [`hook.Add( string eventName, any identifier, function func )`](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/hook/Add)
- [Garry's Mod Wiki](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Main_Page)
- [Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/) (sadly i do not know which lua version is used by gmod)

---

## Disclaimer

This code is completely untested and written of my mind. If this does not work and throws some errors let me know that. I'll correct it then.